# What is the name of this viewcontroller in iOS?

Tags: mobile, ios

[image: viewcontroller]

I just want to know: is this a custom view controller, or it is something provided by Apple, and if that's the case, what is its name?

Answer (score 1):

It's the [Now Playing screen](https://support.apple.com/en-za/HT207230), but this type of view controller does not have a specific name (it's 'just' a variation on a modal view controller), nor is it available via the standard iOS API. It could be that someone wrote an open source library to simulate this behaviour, but I couldn't find it.